# Prestashop 1.7 override front controller from custom theme

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.7

In PrestaShop 1.7, I have my own theme, which is currently the default.
In the product card, I need to display a list of multishop stores.
Since I don't know if it is possible to get information about multishop stores using the default controller **controllers/front/ProductController.php**, I want to extend this controller in my custom theme.

I am creating file **themes/myTheme/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php** with code like this:

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore{
public $multiStores;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    echo 'test';
}
```

}

I expect that on the product card page I will be able to see my text "test".

But unfortunately nothing happens, I conclude that this controller is not connected for some reason.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the situation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a front controller method in a theme like that.

You'll need to override the core frontcontroller by placing
your code inside **/override/controllers/front**

See : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/

Anyway you can achieve the desired result in a cleaner way by
using a proper frontend hook (ie. **hookDisplayHeader**) and build a simple module, checking the context object to see in which **id_shop** you are connected.

Comment: That is, I understand correctly, during the creation of the module, I must declare the creation of a new hook called DisplayHeader and bind my module to it, and then call this module in my theme by calling the DisplayHeader hook?